# Is there a way to dispatch actions synchronously with redux-observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors, redux-observable, optimistic-concurrency

**Description:**
I'm trying to solve a problem of handling optimistic locking or concurrent editing, via communication between the back-end and front-end.

**Current implementation:**
When the front-end makes a request, it includes a specific header of an encoded timestamp that represents the version of the data the user is trying to edit. When it receives a response, the response contains a header of a new encoded timestamp that the front end then stores for the next request.

**Current Problem:**
This works fine when the time between `http.patch()` calls is long enough so that the response is received before the next request is fired. However, if the user is changing the data too quickly, then the requests will fail because they don't have the most up-to-date data (eg. the timestamps aren't lining up).

**Project Details:**
I'm using Angular 7.0+, `@angular-redux/store`, and `redux-observable` for managing the side affects of each `http` request call. Handling multiple requests within the same `epic` is fine, because you can use `concat` in order to make them synchronous. But how could you do this with multiple epics getting called asynchronously?

Another alternative I thought of was using some kind of `http-interceptor` that creates a queue of requests. Each time a request gets fired it's pushed in the queue. When the response is received, the request is taken out of the queue. I just don't know iff the `queue.length > 1` , could it somehow wait for the response before firing off the succession of requests from the queue?

**Has anyone come across this problem before? Or have ideas for how to solve it?**

Comment: [I wrote a similar queuing mechanism to control router navigation](https://medium.com/@nickkell/sequential-router-navigation-in-angular-96d6a17049f7), and maybe it will help you.